# bash script for screen -r

Tags: ssh, cron, centos, gnu-screen

I want to make a bash script that echo's something into one of the screens that I have running (screen -r is how I get to it in SSH).

I was wondering how I would make the script execute itself in screen -r?

I basically just want the script to say something on a minecraft server through the console and would set up a cronjob to say it every x minutes.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-X` option of `screen` to send commands to a running screen session.
Also the `-p` option is useful in this case, as you can use it to preselect a window

As an example you can run a script in a running screen session on windows 0 via:

```
 screen -p 0 -X stuff './fancy_script.sh^M'
```

Note, that you have to append the return key-code to execute the script.

Comment: you can do that via: `ctrl+v` and than `Return`

Answer (score 0):

You can look in /dev/pts. I don't have screen here to test, but you can echo something to an opened terminal with, for example, echo "toto" > /dev/pts/0 (it will be echoed on the first opened terminal).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I've checked the screen sessions running and have tried echoing stuff into it but nothing seems to appear..?